# REST Communication between microservices - Abstract away from host or port in REST call

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, microservices

I just started diving into the microservices topic, so please excuse if this is a stupid question.

Let's say I have two microservices, one providing a REST api and one being an angular microservice for a nice frontend. The angular microservice is expected to communicate with the other microservice.
I saw many examples implementing this and its basically not a big deal. I am well aware of that. However, in all these examples I saw something like this in the angular microservice:

```
this.http.get('http://....:8080....');
```

At first I was just happy to get it running. However, right now I am wondering whether such implementations do not tightly couple the services to each other. In the http URL, we see the host and the port is also fix. That might work well in some cases, but, if our microservice e.g. chooses a port dynamically, we already have a problem right? Then we can't define the port in the other microservice in such a way. The same holds for the host information. If the microservice might be running on different hosts, we cannot always just define the host statically.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Is there any way we can abstract away from these details, i.e. the host or the port but is there another way to find this out dynamically? Or are there other good alternatives for the communication between microservices that don't imply this problem?

I saw examples of services using a service registry. By means of this, we can abstract away from this a bit - no? Is this the only possibility? I am not sure whether this is relevant here, but so far I'm using Spring Boot to implement my microservices.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a confusion here, Microservices should be built around business capability and that means that your Microservice will include both the frontend and the backend. Frontend shouldn't be considered as a microservice.

Frontend could access the backend using sub domain name like http://api.example.com

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Can you please briefly explain why a frontend shouldn't be considered as a microservice? And what if e.g. I have a backend and I want to provide multiple frontends for this backend? Do I then need to copy the backend for every frontend? Moreover, I guess that even if we don't have multiple services here, we can have the same problem - that we don't now on which host at which port our service is executed. Would be glad if you could elaborate on this. Thanks.

Comment: Microservice should be representing a business capability and services should small **Autonomous** services that work together. Autonomous means that each service can respond to its clients regardless of the availability of its dependencies. In e-commerce example services could be "catalog", "Orders" or "Shipping", "Catalog" include viewing all products to consumer and it can view the products regardless of the "Orders" service availability.

Comment: Regarding multiple frontends for the same backend you could use [UI composition](https://jimmybogard.com/composite-uis-for-microservices-a-primer/) or [Backend for frontend](http://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/) and finally after you define the service boundaries you might need service discovery mechanism, you could consider using https://www.consul.io

Comment: Thanks for the links to the two further pages. I upvoted your answer, but I guess it is not displayed, as my reputation is too low. I still hope somebody can refer to something dealing with the original problem. Even if the frontend and backend are together in one microservice, the basic problem can still occur then, I guess.

Comment: I hope its ok If I ask you one further thing. If I have one microservice (consisting of e.g Angular frontend and Java/Spring Boot REST backend), would I build two separate docker files, one for the frontend and one for the backend although it is one microservice? I can also ask a new question concerning this.

Comment: @MDDCoder25 I don’t have experience with Spring but generally I would start with the simpler, in .NET world that usually means one Docker file hosting both backend and front end

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Hossam posted, I played around with [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) now. For this purpose, I studied e.g. the following [Blog](http://blog.trifork.com/2016/12/14/service-discovery-using-consul-and-spring-cloud/). Using Consul, I can do something like the following:`restTemplate.getForObject('http://city-service/rest/city/capital', ...);` instead of `restTemplate.getForObject('http://localhost:8080/rest/city/capital', ...);`. This should also work for other service registries. I still do not not how to do this in e.g. Angular, but perhaps I will create a new question for this.