# Handling service discovery in Angular

Tags: angular, rest, consul, service-discovery

I'm playing around with Microservices at the moment and I also just started using Angular. Now, I am wondering whether/how it is possible to access a service discovery (e.g. Consul) from within Angular? By accessing I mean:

- Register angular app as service at registry (so that it knows host and port angular app is running on)
- Send REST call to other registered service - in best case just using the name of the service.

To express this a bit more precisely: There was one use case, in which I developed two simple services using Spring Boot, I applied the steps from [this](http://blog.trifork.com/2016/12/14/service-discovery-using-consul-and-spring-cloud/) Blog to access one service from the other using Consul. Thus, my REST call looks in the end like this:

> restTemplate.getForObject(http://city-service/rest/city/capital', ...);

What I like about this is that I can abstract away from the host and the port information. Right now, I would like to do the same thing in Angular. Hence, instead of something like this:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/city/capital')
```

I would like to have something similar to this:

```
this.http.get('http://city-service/rest/city/capital')
```

How can I access a service discovery such as Consul (it does not have to be Consul, other ones are fine too) in Angular? As I said, I just started getting to know Angular, so please excuse if this is a stupid question.

I know that some service discoveries (including Consul) provide a REST API to retrieve information about the registered services. However, then I would first need to send a REST request to this explicitly before I could send my actual wanted REST request. I would prefer if there would be another option. Any help is appreciated.

I posted a more general question concerning this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474453/rest-communication-between-microservices-abstract-away-from-host-or-port-in-re/47593412#47593412), but I now concretized the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consul and other service discovery systems are not designed to be accessible from public web and your question isn't really related to Angular.

You can use a Consul aware load balancer such as https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio or https://traefik.io/ to have traffic routed to services which are registered in Consul according to HOST and/or PATH.

Comment: The problem is not limited to Angular, thats right. However, I pointed out that I'm using Angular as it might be possible that Angular provides some easy to use possibility. But then these Consul aware load balancers do not really help me with my issue as I don't know in advance on which host my angular (or other framework) app is running. Is the only other alternative to e.g. deploy some Spring Boot or other kind of application to the same host so that this other app can register itself at Consul (so that I can imply that the angular app is on the same host)?

Comment: are you referring to the client side Angular app or a server that serves .html/.js/.css?

Comment: It is like this: I want to deploy an angular app to a cloud platform such as OpenShift. Some other application should refer to this angular app, so that I need to know the host the app is running on. For this purpose, I would like to use a service discovery. However, the question is also meant more general. If I know that some service is registered there and I want to use it, I should be able to call that service (the second part of the question).

Comment: I think there's some basic misunderstanding of a servers that serves the .html/.js/.css fles and the browser "Angular" app. i think that my answer gives a valid solution for your question. please accept it.